# iteration variable value in jenkins parallel steps

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

```
 registries = [1,2,3,4]
                   
 Map tasks = [:]
 for (j=0;j<=registries.size();j++) {
    tasks["Code ${j}"] = { ->
        sh "touch ${j}"
    }                
 }
              
 parallel(tasks)
 sh "ls -lrt"
```

Above code when executed should create the files 0,1,2,3,4,5

but the last line `ls -lrt` only prints 5 which means it is only taking the last iteration value in all values of map tasks.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

In groovy when you generate the closures in a for loop, the closures are bound to the variable itself and not the value of that variable.
So what happens is that all generated closures are bounded to the free variable `j`, but `j` is bounded to the last value in the for loop, not the value at the time the closure was created and therefore you se only 5s.
You can read more on the groovy delegation behavior [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html).

To solve it you have two options:

1. Use groovy iteration functions (like `each`) instead of the `for` as in these functions the iteration variable is a different instance for each iteration and therefore the closure is bounded to its own unique parameter, and the values will work as expected.
   In your case:

   ```
   registries = [1,2,3,4]                
   Map tasks = [:]
   registries.each { j ->
      tasks["Code ${j}"] = { sh "touch ${j}" }             
   }              
   parallel(tasks)
   sh "ls -lrt"
   ```

   Or using the `collectEntries` method:

   ```
   registries = [1,2,3,4]                
   parallel registries.collectEntries { j ->
      ["Code ${j}" : { sh "touch ${j}" }]            
   }              
   sh "ls -lrt"
   ```
2. Create a locally scooped 'dummy' variable that will capture the value of each iteration and bound it to the closure. The dummy parameter is actually used for preventing mutation of the parameter before the execution of the closure, and you have to assign it outside the closure definition.
   In your case:

   ```
   registries = [1,2,3,4]                   
   Map tasks = [:]
   for (j=0;j<=registries.size();j++) {
       def registry = j //if we don't do this and just use i below, it would equal 5 in each execution.
       tasks["Code ${registry}"] = { ->
           sh "touch ${registry}"
       }                
   }

   parallel(tasks)
   sh "ls -lrt"
   ```

In both options a new variable is created for each iteration and the expected value is bounded to the closure.