# Groovy[Jenkins] how to iterate over a paramter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

so I want to explain you what I'm doing and the struggle:

**GOAL:**

I'm trying to create a parallel pipeline to run 3 pods for each of our code tenants;

GOAL - 3 pods each executing  a maven process
params.testTenant is a parameter in plugin and it's values are "test1, test2, test3"

I get 3 pods each with the name of the tenant, but when I do "println tenant" **I get only test3** inside each of the pods

`println tenant`

should give test1, then test2, then test3
Why is this happening :(

```groovy
parallelMap = [:]

for (def tenant in params.testTenant.tokenize( ',' )) {
     parallelMap["$tenant"] = {
         nodeContainer(
                 [image(alias: 'tests',
                        imageName: 'test,
                        alwaysPull: true)]) {
                  println tenant
 
             stage('Checkout SCM') {
                 checkout scm
             }
```

Comment: To solve it change your for loop line to: `params.testTenant.tokenize(',').each {tenant ->`. See the following [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070368/iteration-variable-value-in-jenkins-parallel-steps/68808059#68808059) for a full explanation.

Comment: That is great and it works. One small question extra to that. How do I so to say add 3 more variables that will be changed for each pod. I  understand now how do I do with "tenant", what is there was also "server" and "url"

Comment: I am not sure i understand what do you mean - can you give an example?

Comment: params.testTenant.tokenize(',').each {tenant that works, but if I had ALSO other variables that are different for each instance like each.environment, each.url . Do I need to create nested for loops for each variable that I want to iterrate over

Comment: Yes, or create a list of dictionaries (maps), in which each map contains all relevant data for the iterations and go over that list.

Comment: Can you give a quick example? I couldn't understand it fully

Comment: `[[env:'env0', url:'url0', tenant:'tenant0'],[env:'env1', url:'url1', tenant:'tenant1'],...].each { println("${it.env} ${it.url} ${it.tenant}")}`